# Know what the current route is in a component outside of the Stack Navigator with React Navigation?

Tags: react-navigation

I have a component which is within the `NavigationContainer` component but outside of the `Stack Navigator`. Can I know what the current route is within the component? I cant use the `useRoute` hook as it errors:

> Couldn't find a route object. Is your component inside a screen in a navigator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to follow this guide from the `react-navigation` [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating-without-navigation-prop). It explains how to gain access to a `NavigationContainer` `ref` which you can then use to access the current navigation state of your app, even outside of components.

Here's a short demo, in case this link breaks in the future.

```
// App.js

import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { navigationRef } from './Navigation';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}>{/* ... */}</NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

```
// Navigation.js

import React from 'react';

export const navigationRef = React.createRef();

// You can export navigation functions to use throughout your app, without accessing the `navigation` prop.
export function navigate(name, params) {
  navigationRef.current?.navigate(name, params);
}

// This is the function you want, it will return the complete navigation state
export function getRootState() {
  return navigationRef.current?.getRootState();
}
```